# Why ArrayBlockingQueue in Java use locks and conditions?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Can someone explain me why `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue` use locks and conditions instead of `synchronized`  and  `wait/notify`?

Comment: This question is offtopic on this forum, but it is perhaps because the locks being new constructs have some advantages over the older ones.

Comment: Why this is offtopic?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I also do not think this is offtopic but definitely duplicate as Andreas mentioned. @DPM Synchronization vs Lock is a better place to read the anser